# Netty in Spring and slf4j Logger Factory

Tags: spring, configuration, netty, slf4j

My basic question is. How do I configure Netty to use slf4j in Spring? I keep getting the error below in Spring but not eclipse using the slf4j jars with the log4j bridge and api in the path. I am using Spring Tools suite, spring 3.2.3, and Netty 4 (post jboss).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

The program fails at the line where I instantiate the connection group after I try setting the default logging factory.

I am really new to Netty and slf4j. I have been banging my head against this one for a while and done a bit of research on Stack Overflow and the internet. I managed to get Netty working with slf4j in eclipse and used the Internal Logger Factory. I tried configuring slf4j in a similar way to log4j (A properties file with appenders).

I used the following code for the InternalLoggerFactory in both of the following ways with the appropriate imports.

```
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Slf4JLoggerFactory());
```

and

```
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(Slf4JLoggerFactory.getDefaultFactory());
```

These lines are placed immediately before my initialization of the connection group but I tried them in my Main App/Driver's main method as well.

Thanks for any help. I would and do really appreciate it.

Comment: In slf4j many things depend on the slf4j libaries that are in the classpath. Could you please add a list of slf4j jars that you use (`*slf4j*.jar`)?

Comment: jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, slf4j-simple-1.75.jar, slf4j-api-1.75.jar,log4j-to-slf4j-2.0-beta8.jar,log4j-1.2.16.jar and thanks

Comment: as an update. could the problem be with logback classic? the version is 1.0.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

´org.slf4j.LoggerFactory´ is part of ´slf4j-api-1.75.jar´, so it is likely that you have some deployment problem. -- Check that this jar is really in the classpath of you application, or if you have an web application, then check that this jar is deployed to you application server.

One other thing (that is maybe not the cause of your problem) is that you have `log4j-1.2.16.jar` and `log4j-to-slf4j-2.0-beta8.jar`. This is will lead to other problems, because `log4j-to-slf4j` is a log4j-to-slf4j bridge, that forward log4j loggers to slf4j. On the ohter hand you have the real log4j in your classpath too. I would remove `log4j-1.2.16.16`. I hope this [slf4j docu](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) describe it a bit better than me.

An other point that brothers me, is that you use different version of slf4j. I strongly recommend to use the same version for all slf4j libs!

Comment: This is close to the answer and I really appreciate the response. I had descended into dependency nightmare and you saved me. I really appreciate that. I actually found that a jar exists called sfl4j-jdk in of the site where the docs are. After cleansing my path, it solved everything. Strangely, it is never mentioned anywhere.